# Wordpress loop filter by meta_value

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops

I have a user loop where i filter the users by a meta value:

```
<?php
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'fields' => 'ID',
    'meta_key' => 'country',
    'meta_value' => "china",
    'compare' => 'IN' ) );
    $user_ids = $user_query->get_results(); 
?>
```

this works. But i want to show people who have entered something like "china, russia, norway" not only "china", so

```
'compare' => 'IN' ) );
```

must be replaced by something like "contains", is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
<?php  

// args
$args = array(                      
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
'key' => 'country',
'value' => 'germany',
'compare' => 'LIKE'
))
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {

foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
}

} else {
echo 'No users found.';
}

?>

<?php 
// aaaaaand reset ...
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, but just to clarify, you want to be able to search the 'meta_value' for users that have entered "china" but could also have entered other values? If that's the case, I think you want to use LIKE in your compare.

```
<?php
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'fields' => 'ID',
    'meta_key' => 'country',
    'meta_value' => "china",
    'compare' => 'LIKE' ) );
    $user_ids = $user_query->get_results(); 
?>
```

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Parameters)

Comment: This doesn't work. It only works when the meta_value is "china", but when it is like "china, sweden, germany" than nothing is shown.